# Display Notification from Alarm Manager

Tags: android, notifications, apple-push-notifications, alarmmanager, android-toast

I have an Alarm Manager that puts the current Time in a message and outputs that message in a Toast Message.

What I want to do is to output a notification instead of a toast message and have been struggling to do so.

The Alarm Manager works. The Notification also works currently when it is pressed by a button (currently unconnected to the alarm manager).

Here is my button that is getting the toast from the Broadcast Receiver:

```
public void onetimeTimer(View view){
    Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
    if(alarm != null){
        alarm.setOnetimeTimer(context);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Here is my Alarm Manager Broadcast Receiver:

```
public class AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

final public static String ONE_TIME = "onetime";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "YOUR TAG");
    //Acquire the lock
    wl.acquire();

    //You can do the processing here update the widget/remote views.
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    StringBuilder msgStr = new StringBuilder();

    if(extras != null && extras.getBoolean(ONE_TIME, Boolean.FALSE)){
     msgStr.append("One time Timer : ");
    }
    Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
   // msgStr.append(formatter.format(new Date()));

    //msgStr.append();

    Toast.makeText(context, msgStr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    //Release the lock
    wl.release();

}
```

Here is the method in the Broadcast receiver:

```
public void setOnetimeTimer(Context context){
AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
   Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
   intent.putExtra(ONE_TIME, Boolean.TRUE);
   PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
   am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), pi);
   }
```

Here is the Notification that is working seperately behind a different button that I would like to be set off by the alarm manager button being pressed.

```
Button btnNotifyWorkout = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNotifyWorkout);
            btnNotifyWorkout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent  = new Intent();
                    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(HomeActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
                    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(HomeActivity.this)
                                                .setTicker("TickerTitle")
                                                .setContentTitle("Lukes App")
                                                .setContentText("You have a workout due today")
                                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                                                .setContentIntent(pIntent).getNotification();

                    noti.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                    NotificationManager nm  = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    nm.notify(0, noti);
                } 
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your notification code inside "onReceive" in Alarm manager receiver

But with a few tweaks:

```
Intent intent  = new Intent();
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(context)
    .setTicker("TickerTitle")
    .setContentTitle("Lukes App")
    .setContentText("You have a workout due today")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContentIntent(pIntent).getNotification();

noti.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
NotificationManager nm  = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
nm.notify(0, noti);
```

Comment: I added the notification between w1.acquire and w1.release but it is not alllowing  NOTIFICATION_SERVICE, I am getting the error: "NOTIFICATION_SERVICE cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: Right, sorry, I forgot to adjust that as well, just replace that with Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE. I've adjusted the answer

Comment: Thats great that solved my issue perfectly! Thanks for the help! :)